# Add fade effect between video and png image FFMPEG android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

By using below command we can merge video and image together. I not an expert to build ffmpeg commands.

```
String cmd = "-t 5 -i " + videoPath +
                " -loop 1 -t 5 -i " + imagePath +
                " -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc" +
                " -filter_complex [1][0]scale2ref[2nd][ref];[ref][0:a][2nd][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" +
                " -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 -map [v] -map [a] -preset veryfast " + outputPath;
```

Any one who have idea to add a transition effect between video and image.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make fade in/out effect between concatenate videos using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669428/how-to-make-fade-in-out-effect-between-concatenate-videos-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: convert your image to a video and then use the method mentioned here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669428/how-to-make-fade-in-out-effect-between-concatenate-videos-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: thank you for the answer. i already checked the stack overflow post  but i need to merge video and image together it is compulsory

Comment: I  want to add some parameters to my existing command but that is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: See [Create video with 5 images with fadeIn/out effect in ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/834035/110524).